# wxPython: Right-click with mouse does not set focus

Tags: python, focus, wxpython, copy-paste, right-click

My GUI currently has right-click options (Cut, Copy, Paste)

However, I realize when I right-click over my search bar (wx.SearchCtrl) to try and paste, focus is not set onto the search bar, therefore I cannot paste.

```
self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.OnShowPopup)

def OnShowPopup(self, event):
   """ Obtain right-click selection """
   pos = event.GetPosition()
   pos = self.panel.ScreenToClient(pos)
   self.panel.PopupMenu(self.rightClickMenu, pos)

def OnPopupItemSelected(self, event):
   """ Display right-click menu """
   item = self.rightClickMenu.FindItemById(event.GetId())
   text = item.GetText()
   elif text == "Paste":
      self.OnPaste()

def OnPaste(self, event = None):
   """ Paste content from clipboard """
   text = self.FindFocus()
   if text:
      if isinstance(text, wx.TextCtrl):
         text.Paste()
```

Here is my idea:
Get the position of mouse when right-clicked. Then use that position to set focus on the Ctrl that holds that position.

Is this possible? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the object of where right-clicked was performed, then setFocus after selecting Paste. 
The reason why event.GetEventObject().SetFocus() does not work is most likely because after selecting Paste from the PopupMenu, the TextCtrl loses focus. So text would not print there

```
def OnShowPopup(self, event):
   """ Obtain right-click selection """
   pos = event.GetPosition()
   pos = self.panel.ScreenToClient(pos)
   self.rightClickSelected = event.GetEventObject()
   self.panel.PopupMenu(self.rightClickMenu, pos)

def OnPaste(self, event = None):
   """ Paste content from clipboard """
   self.rightClickSelected.SetFocus()
   if isinstance(self.rightClickSelected, wx.TextCtrl):
      self.rightClickSelected.Paste()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def OnShowPopup(self, event):
      """ Obtain right-click selection """

      pos = event.GetPosition()
      pos = self.panel.ScreenToClient(pos)
      event.GetEventObject().SetFocus()
      self.panel.PopupMenu(self.rightClickMenu, pos)
```

would work fine I think ...

Comment: It does not work. I have tried replacing my_wx_search_ctrl with self, self.panel, and self.search.

Comment: edited to give focus to specific widget ... you could popup your menu from EVT_RIGHT_DOWN also and get rid of the binding to contextmenu event

Comment: I started using the wxPython Widget Inspection Tool, and it shows that whenever I right-click on TextCtrl or SearchCtrl, wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU is activated. No sign of EVT_RIGHT_DOWN anywhere

Comment: I am using: wxPython 2.8.10.1, Windows 7, Python 2.4

Comment: I tried to skip the wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU event with event.skip(), hopefully wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN shows up, but still nothing. Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/TMPWQjiikx4

Comment: hmmm well Im at a loss :/  If you can put up a full (minimal) working example on pastebin or something I could take a look

Comment: Please look into wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN & wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU. I have tried using search.Bind etc also: http://pastebin.com/YnLPe6hC

Comment: hmmm ... when I tried it, it worked fine just the way you have it... data was pasted in to the search field, what OS are you on (btw your interface looks very nice)

Comment: Both Windows and Linux. Paste works with the default right-click option (I can use the self.rightClickMenu to pop-up my custom made right-click menu, but so far it only works if the interface recognizes wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU) The problem is wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN is not recognized ("hi" is not printed)

Comment: I started learning Python 3 months ago, and wxPython a month ago. Took me awhile to get this interface :/

Comment: event.GetEventObject().SetFocus() did not set focus ... it returns None

Comment: I think SetFocus() is called after I have selected Paste

Comment: event.GetEventObject() will get whatever control you right clicked on ... and trigger it with the EVT_CONTEXT_MENU ... get rid of the ON_RIGHT_DOWN binding.  SetFocus will set focus on the item but yes it returns None ...

Comment: Not for Linux. btw I used: self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.OnShowPopup)

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I used ... maybe try printing `event.GetEventObject()`  (I am using py2.6 ... but that shouldnt matter)

Comment: event.GetEventObject() gives out an object. but event.GetEventObject().SetFocus() returns None

Comment: of coarse it returns None ... it never returns anything ... it just gives focus to what its called on ... there is no return

Comment: that code you posted seems to work fine for windows 7 (explicitly setting to self.search) ... I cant really tell you much about linux though :/

Comment: If I edit the OnPaste function with "print self.FindFocus()", it prints out None. That means by the time Paste is selected nothing is focus.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help so far. I will test out Windows when I get home. I will keep you updated

Comment: if i print self.FindFocus() in onPast it says <wx.TextCtrl....> just fyi what Im seeing ... why not just use `self.search` instead of `self.FindFocus()` will you be needing other text boxes to get pastes?

Comment: I might need other boxes to get paste later. But anyways I just figured another way :)

Comment: Joran please help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431669/wxpython-mouse-left-click-evt-left-down-on-searchctrl